# Summing the values entered in textInput in RShiny

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I am developing the Shiny app and I am unable to sum the values entered in dynamically created textInput.
The **RCode** used is as follows:

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(3, offset = 3,wellPanel(textOutput("text2"))),
        column(3,wellPanel(textOutput("text3"))),
        column(3,wellPanel(textOutput("text4")))
      )
    )
    server <- function(input, output, session){
      observeEvent(input$view, {
        output$inputGroup = renderUI({
#code for generating textBoxes and corresponding Id's dynamically 
          input_list <- lapply(1:(nrow(df())*3), function(i) {
            inputName <- paste("id", i, sep = "")
            textInputRow<-function (inputId,value) 
            {
                        textAreaInput(inputName,"", width = "200px", height = "43px", resize = "horizontal")
            }
            column(4,
                   textInputRow(inputName, "")
            )

          })
          do.call(tagList, input_list)

        })

      })
#code for adding the values and displaying the sum
     output$text2 <- renderText({
        tot = nrow(df())*3
        sum1 = 0
        for(lim in 1:tot){
          if(lim %% 3 == 1){
            inp = paste("id",lim)
            sum1 = sum1 + input[[inp]]
          }
        }
      }) 
    }
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The output is : 
[image: Output]

Can anyone help me with this code?

Comment: What's the error or roadblock that you are facing. Could you modify your code to be reproducible?

Comment: The problem is the textboxes and the corresponding InputId's are generated dynamically. I want to sum the textboxes whose InputId's satisfy the condition(last "if" condition where lim is the total number say 18.) and display the total sum in TextOutput. @amrrs

Answer (score 0):

While your question is modified, Here's a reproducible code for summing values entered in the textbox:

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput("input1", "Input1", 1),
    textInput("input2", "Input2", 2),
    tags$h3('Result:'),
    verbatimTextOutput("value")
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$value <- renderText({ as.numeric(input$input1) + as.numeric(input$input2)})
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

[image: Output]